# Trying to grasp the concept of an algorithm that sorts numbers from 0 to 99999

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, recursion

I'm trying to grasp the idea of a sort algorithm that needs to work like this:

Given an arbitrary array filled with numbers ranging from 0 to 99999, I'm required to write an algorithm that orders these numbers, beginning with the smallest and ending with the biggest. The algorithm should work like this: Each number is supposed to receive a certain position in one out of ten arrays respectively in arrays with the numbers 0 to 9. (we were given the hint to simply use a two-dimensional matrix for this). For example, the number 51525 should be positioned in the array 5 and the number 5673 in the array 0 since 5673 will be interpreted as 05673. This matrix will be part of the first method, and this is the same method where we actually want to sort the numbers. Furthermore, we need a second method that receives, I think, a one-dimensional array where we put in a number beforehand. This method is now supposed to generate an extented array and copy the transfered array (meaning the number inside the transfered 1x1 array) into it. So, we would have an array with two elements now, one being the number from before. This new array is now returned, although I don't know how. We need to work with recursion too.

My attempt works the somehow like this:

We give an array to the sorting method, work with a switch-case-construct, divide every number by 10000 and position them with respect to the remainder (case 0, case 1, ...). The problem that arises here, of course, is that we might face the situation where we would copy two numbers on the same field, which would overwrite the first number. So the solution might lay in the second method where we take such an 1x1 array filled with a number, extent it and return it to the sorting method again. Now, it can fill the array again, and it case there is another number that needs to be positioned on this exact field, we could extent the array again. That would be my recursion. The recursion ancor might look like this: "If a field contains no number or only one number, ...".

What I don't get straight now is the implementation of this idea. For example, if I would extent an 1x1 array in order to fill it with another number and return it, how should the sorting method work with it? I mean, it's not like I could just stick it to the former matrix.

I'm not asking for a code here, just wondering if somebody is familiar with this kind of sorting algorithm and if this somebody could give me a push in the right direction I am required to go.

Comment: Voting to close. This question belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The algorithm is [Radix-Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort).

Comment: Are you sure? Does Radix-Sort work with the method of extending arrays?

Comment: @Julian - The example of a matrix suggests a radix sort that works from least significant digit (first) to most significant digit. The matrix would need to be [10][size of array] or [size of array][10] to avoid having to dynamically resize the matrix. The matrix is essentially duplicating the trays of a [card sorter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_card_sorter).

Answer (score 2):

You're assuming that each array has integers as its elements.  The comparable method with which I'm familiar works with an array of lists: you put all the numbers starting with 5 into element 5 of your array.

The recursion step passes this to a method that sorts on the 2nd digit, then on the 3rd, and so on.  (Note that this method can be the same as the top one.)  Each pass makes the list smaller, until sorting on the last digit gives you a single element in each array element.

Now you work your way back up the call stack.  At each level, you simply append the array elements in order from 0 to 9, resulting in a list roughly 10 times the size of the previous level's.

Is that clear enough to get you moving?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your method might be the same that I'm required to implement. I'm also supposed to sort on the 2nd, 3rd digit and so on.

Comment: Great to hear it.  When the time comes, remember to accept an answer to get the question properly archived -- even if you have to write a summary yourself.